# Why can't I play multiplayer in Red Dead Redemption all of a sudden?

Tags: ps3, psn, red-dead-redemption

I've been playing Red Dead Redemption multiplayer for years just fine until a four days ago.

I now see multiple weird problems such as:

- Starting gang hideouts in free roam and having them complete after a few kills.
- Connecting to game type seems to kick out other players, or lock up.
- Sometimes when I connect to gang shoot out a see a small image of the scores all showing zeros and all other players are kicked out.
- When I do connect very few other players seem to be around.
- I can see the NPC locals wandering around (especially in Macfarlane's ranch) during gang shootouts.

all this makes on-line unplayable.  All the users on my ps3 are effected, I have tried re-installing RDR, deleting my local save game, creating a new user and trying that one, all to no avail.

I can play GTA5 on-line just fine, so I do not think it's my router.  Could this be a problem with my ps3?

thanks.

Comment: Use this link, http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/requests/new
Rockstar Support
support.rockstargames.com
Please enter the details of your request and we will respond as soon as possible. If you are reporting a bug or other in-game problem, please be sure to include all the steps leading up to the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be [recent problem with RDR](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200560908-Red-Dead-Redemption-Online-servers-down-?locale=en-us) and all players are affected. As already suggested in the referenced topic submit a support ticket. More tickets, more likely the fix will be sooner.

Comment: cheers petr abdulin, I wave also seen in the armadillo lobby before a gang shootout starts a local cowboy limping around with no arms!

Comment: I'd vote you up my rep is too low.  happy xmas.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to have been fixed with the 1.08 update, go get it now.

Here are the [Release Notes](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202427216--6-19-14-Red-Dead-Redemption-Title-Update-1-08-Notes) for the 1.08 Update.